# pointer to char vs pointer to arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I thought I had a decent knowledge of *pointers* until I decided to review some so called trivial examples.

One thing I know is that when declaring an array say:

```
int arr[2] {3, 5};
```

`arr` will hold the value of the first element in the array so attempting to print that (`cout << arr`) gives obviously the address of `arr[0]`. Even thought my program uses pointers it's still similar.

My question is why can I print `h` and have `bonjour` as output, but I can't do the same with `p`?

It also looks like when I increment `h++` and print it again I get `onjour`. How are pointers different with `char`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char* h = "bonjour";
    int k[4]{3, 4, 5, 6};
    int * p = k;

    std::cout << "Hello, "<< h << "!\n";
}
```

Comment: Outputting arrays of characters as strings is so common that there is a << overload for `const char *` that does it for you. Practically no one ever wants to output an array of int without some special formatting, and even then how would << know when to stop? With a char array, 0 terminates the string, but 0 is just another number in an int array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you stream `h`, you are using [this overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
```

But when you stream `p`, you are using [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

The former will print every byte until it gets to a `\0`, the latter will simply print the address. That is - there's simply a special case for `const char*` that you're taking advantage of.

Answer (score 2):

> why can i print `h` and have `bonjour` as output and i can't do the same with `p`? it also looks like when i increment `h++` and print it again i get `onjour`. how are pointers different with `char`?

The standard library provides two overloads of the `operator<<` function for dealing with pointers.

A member function overload:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

and a non-member function overload:

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
```

The first one is invoked when `cout << ptr` is used for all pointers that are not of type `char*` or `char const*`. The second is used for all pointers that are of tpe `char*` or `char const*`. The second one outputs everything up to the terminating null characters while the first one outputs just the pointer value.

That explains the output.

It's instructive to understand **why** the standard library treats them differently.

The language and the standard libraries make exceptions to the null terminated strings that are represented by `char*` and `char const*`.  When dealing with strings, the null character (`'\0'`) acts as a sentinel value that marks the end of the string. There is no such value for other types. Hence, an `int*` cannot be treated the same was a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

`char*` can be special in some circumstances, because C decided to use it for representing strings. In that case a `char*` refers to a null terminated array of characters, aka C-string. The reason you can print `h` but not `p` is because there exists a function that does the special handling for `char*`:

```
 std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char*);
```

You could provide your own overload to print null terminated integer arrays:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int* arr) {
   while (int i = *arr++) {
      os << i;
      if (*arr) os << ", ";
   }
   return os;
}

int main()
{
  const int arr[] = {1, 2 ,3, 4, 0};
  std::cout << arr << "\n";
}
```

However, this is extremely dangerous because most integer arrays are not terminated by a zero and not all pointer to integers are arrays.

Comment: C doesn't use `char*` for *storing* strings. It uses `char*` to *point to* a string.

Comment: so `if (*arr)` evaluates to `true` if there is a value and `false` otherwise? interesting. So instead of the usual `for loop`  to print (or manupulate idividual element) the array `for (int i=0, i<sizeof(array);)`, i can just use a `while loop` then: `while((*array)) do somestuff and array++`!(?).

Comment: @Bobby: That only works if the last element is 0. :-)

Comment: @KeithThompson, you're absolutely right. I changed it.

Comment: @Bobby: `if (*arr)` is essentially equivalent to `if (*arr != 0)`. (In C it's exactly equivalent; C++ operator overloading might create other opportunities.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with `operator <<` for `char*` and `int*` more than anything else. C programmers are used to null terminated strings printing out so a method was created to print them. `int`s can be printed directly. A `char` will not be able to print out a whole string.